# Editing NSString's

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to change the value of an existing NSString. However it keeps giving me an 'Expected Expression' error.
I know that it is possible to do this but i am not sure exactly how to go about doing it. maybe it's just me being a noob...

Here's my code:

```
NSString *object = @"";

int randObj = rand() % 2;
switch (randObj) {
    case 0:
       NSString *object = @"object 1";//error here
       break;

    case 1:
       NSString *object = @"object 2";//and here
        break;

        default:
        break;
```

The code **should** be changing the value of the `object` variable but it just throws an error.

Comment: And this would be implemented much easier as an array of strings and getting the value based on the random index.

Comment: Nobody lives twice.  Neither does an Objective-C variable.

Comment: Yes but an array would not be practical for what I am trying to accomplish, plus I don't have a clue of how to use them...

Comment: BTW - Doing `x % 1` will always give you 0. Do you really want either 0 or 1? Then do `int randObj = arc4random_uniform(2);`.

Comment: What about int randObj = rand % 2; ?

Comment: That will work. Be sure you are seeding `rand` or every time you run your app you will get the exact same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: What if the rand thing is inside a button (I.e. When the button is pressed it will run the rand sequence)

Comment: Read the man page for `rand`. You need to seed it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've declared your string, just use it. Don't declare it again (by doing `NSString *object = ...;`

E.g:

```
NSString *object = @"";

int randObj = rand() % 1;
switch (randObj) {
    case 0:
        object = @"object 1";
        break;

    case 1:
        object = @"object 2";
        break;

        default:
        break;
```

I would recommend reading up on the Objective-C fundamentals, specifically how to use variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare variables inside a case label within switch. You can initialize them tough. If you wish to update the NSString* object declared outside. Just do

```
switch (randObj) {
case 0:
   object = @"object 1";
    break;

case 1:
   object = @"object 2";
    break;

    default:
    break;
```

Comment: Yes, you can declare variables inside a case label within a switch. If the 1st line happens to declare a variable you need to put the code in a block (curly braces). Of course in this case, the OP shouldn't be using new variables as you state.

Comment: @Computer_whiz Why did you accept this answer over the other? The other was first and this one is wrong (the code is right but the statement before the code is wrong).

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new to this website and I thought you can accept multiple answers.

Comment: @Computer_whiz You can upvote as many as you wish but you can only accept one.